# How to make POST get_or_create related Resources in tastypie

Tags: tastypie

I'm using Tastypie to create a REST API for a Django app and want to be able to create new objects and related objects in one POST. The related objects are specified by a name used to look them up, and I want to create new ones if the name is not found.

Given Django models like this:

```py
class Product(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=32)

class Release(Model):
    product = ForeignKey(to=Product, related_name='releases')
    version = CharField(max_length=32)
```

And these Tastypie resources:

```py
class ProductResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'product'

class ReleaseResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Release.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'release'

    def hydrate_product(self, bundle):
        """Replace product name with id of existing/created one."""
        product = Product.objects.get_or_create(name=bundle.data['product'])
        bundle.data['product'] = product.id
        return bundle
```

And an empty database

When I POST this data to my tastypie REST API:

```
POST /api/release {
    "product": "Cool Widget",
    "version": "1.2.3",
}
```

Then I want these model objects to be created:

```py
product = Product(name="Cool Widget")
release = Release(product=product, version="1.2.3")
```

But I get an exception something like this:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "product_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, 1.2.3).
```

And the hydrate_product() method is not called.

When I add this class property to ReleaseResource:

```py
product = fields.ToOneField(ProductResource, 'product')
```

Then I get something like this:

```
NotFound: An incorrect URL was provided 'Cool Widget' for the 'ProductResource' resource.
```

How do I replace the product name in the bundle with the URI of the created/existing Product object having that name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think my mistake is in trying to modify the purpose of relation fields. They should be left to work normally if my resource actually includes them.

I should just declare `ReleaseResource.product` as a `CharField` and implement `Release.obj_create` to use `Product.objects.get_or_create` for the related `Product` object when creating the new `Release`.

```py
class ReleaseResource(ModelResource):
    product = CharField(attribute='product__name')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Release.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'release'

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs)
        product = Product.objects.get_or_create(name=bundle.data['product'])[0]
        super(ModelResource, self).obj_create(bundle, product=product, **kwargs)
```

It doesn't seem clear enough in the doco that *no* relation fields are populated on a `ModelResource` automatically, you have to explicitly declare *all* relation fields, not just reverse ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
class ReleaseResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Release.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'release'

    def hydrate_product(self, bundle):
        """Replace product name with id of existing/created one."""
        product = Product.objects.get_or_create(name=bundle.data['product'])
        bundle.data['product'] = product.id
        return bundle
```

`hydrate_product` won't be triggered because `hydrate_*` generated based on Tastypie fields where related aren't there by default.

I am not 100% sure about it but I would try this:

```
class ReleaseResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Release.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'release'

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        """Replace product name with id of existing/created one."""
        product = Product.objects.get_or_create(name=bundle.data['product'])
        bundle.obj.product = product
        return bundle
```

Note: I assign product object to `bundle.obj.product`.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I found the simplest solution is to declare a CharField for the name and get_or_create the related object in an implementation of obj_create. See my answer on this thread.